# Combine two clips from two different videos into one video with javascript (client side)?

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg, client, video-processing

Does anyone know if this is possible?

The closest thing I found to what I am looking for is this: http://bgrins.github.io/videoconverter.js/

But the "docs" are very minimal.

Comment: What do you mean by "combine"?

Comment: split screen, or like a collage

Answer (score 7):

You can add 2 videos in one video element

```js
var myvid = document.getElementById('myvideo');
var myvids = [
  "http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4", 
  "http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4"
  ];
var activeVideo = 0;

myvid.addEventListener('ended', function(e) {
  // update the new active video index
  activeVideo = (++activeVideo) % myvids.length;

  // update the video source and play
  myvid.src = myvids[activeVideo];
  myvid.play();
});
```

```html
<video src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" id="myvideo" width="320" height="240" controls style="background:black">
</video>
```

Comment: I feel that this response, while well documented, misses the point. What the above does is merely change the 'src' attribute of the video, but the sources themselves are still two separate videos, not a combined one.